# How to configure an exchange for messages that raise exceptions in consumers with MassTransit for RabbitMQ in order to reuse them later on?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am wondering how to configure an exchange for messages that raise exceptions in consumers with MassTransit for RabbitMQ in order to replay them later on? Is that possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works out of the box without any configuration. All messages that caused the consumer to fail are placed to the dead-letter queue as [described in the documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/exceptions.html) in detail.